# Ramsey-Kuratowski numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

A simple graph is an ordered pair of sets $\,\Gamma:=(V\,E)\,$ such that
$\,E\subseteq\binom V2.\ $ Kuratowski graph of the first kind is
$\,K_n:=\left(V\,\,\binom V2\right),\,$ where $\,n:=|V|.\,$ And of the second type is

$$ K_{m\,n}\,:=\,(W\!\cup\!V\,\, \mu(W\times V)) $$

where $\,W\cap V=\emptyset,\,$ and $\,|W|=m\,$ and $\,|V|=n,\,$ and

$$\,\mu(W\times V)\,:=\,\{\{w\,v\}:\, (w\,v)\in W\times V\} $$

> 

**Q1 (single)**  What is the least natural number $\,s\,$
such that for every edge red-green coloring of $\,K_s,\,$ graph
$\,K_s\,$ contains a red subgraph isomorphic to $\,K_5\,$ or
a green subgraph isomorphic to $\,K_{3\,3}\,$ ? Call this number
$\,\mbox{RK}_{rg}.$

**Q2 (double)**  What is the least natural number $\,d\,$ such
that for every edge red-green coloring of $\,K_d,\,$ graph $\,K_d\,$
contains a unicolored subgraph (totally red or totally green) isomorphic
to $\,K_5\,$ or to $\,K_{3\,3}\,$ ? Call this number
$\,\mbox{RK}_{xx}.$

**Q3 (triple)**  What is the least natural number $\,D\,$ such
that every for every edge red-green coloring of $\,K_d,\,$ graph
$\,K_d\,$ contains two unicolored subgraphs of the same color, one
isomorphic to $\,K_5\,$ and the other one to $\,K_{3\,3}\,$ ? Call
this number $\,\mbox{RK}_{YY}.$

> ***REMARK**   Of course, the above questions allude to Kuratowski's characterization of planar graphs (the theorem covered even more than graphs).*

We have
$$ \mbox{RK}_{xx}\,\le\,\mbox{RK}_{rg}\,\le\,\mbox{RK}_{YY} $$

and, *let me quote* **T**aras **B**anakh,

$$ RK_{xx}\le R(5,5)\le 48 $$

*There is a conjecture that* $\,\,R(5,5)=43.\,$ (*end of quote*).

Comment: I hope the graph $K_{3,3}$ should be defined as a suitably two-colored $K_6$.

Comment: Observe that $RK_{xx}\le R(5,5)\le 48. The is a conjecture that R(5,5)=43.

Comment: @TarasBanakh, your comment about $K_{3,3}$, I don't understand (of course edges of $\,K_6\,$ cannot be two-colored).

Comment: I think @Taras's question addresses the word "induce". When you get a monocolor $K_{3,3}$, do you insist to have all other edges between the six vertices to have the other color? If not, it is better to replace 'induce' by some other word.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov, I mean that each of the graphs $\,K_{3\,3}\, $ and $\,K_5\,$ should have edges of one color (all $9$ edges of $\,K_{3\,3}\,$ should be of the same color). How should I write it more clearly? You're welcome to try your hand at editing my Q.

Comment: @WlodAA The problem with the current formulation is that if you have a monochrome $K_6$, then you also have a monochrome $K_{3,3}$. But I suggest that asking the question you had in mind something different: there exists a copy of $K_6$ whose red colored edges (say) form a subgraph isomorphic to $K_{3,3}$ (and then green colored edges form two disjoint copies of $K_3$). So, which version of the question had  you in mind?

Comment: @WlodAA What about this form of the question: find the smallest $n$ such that for any graph $\Gamma$ on $n$ vertices either $\Gamma$ or the complement of $\Gamma$ in $K_n$ is non-planar. Is this the same as your $RK_{xx}$?

Comment: @TarasBanakh why should it be the same? Non-planarity is implied by a homeomorphic copy of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$, not isomorphic.

Comment: It's not enough for an answer, but I can show $13 \leq \mathrm{RK}_{xx}$. To see this, we need a $2$-coloring of the edges of $K_{12}$ that avoids any monochromatic copies of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$. To get one, just label the vertices with ordered pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a \in \{1,2,3\}$ and $b \in \{1,2,3,4\}$, and then put an edge between two vertices iff either their first coordinates are equal or their second coordinates are equal.

Comment: I have to rush now, am about to play in the last round of a local senior chess tournament (I am 3:0 and will play against the other highest scorer, who has 2.5pts). I'll see you later.

Comment: @TarasBanakh, may I quote your useful comment about $R(5\,5)$ in my *Question* ?

Comment: Everybody who has partial answers, I encourage you to post them as *Answers*. This way you will stimulate the progress -- in real-time -- for the given topic. Somehow, one reacts to *Answers* stronger than to comments.

Comment: @WlodAA Of course, you can!

Comment: @TarasBanakh, thank you -- done.

Comment: I hope that I clarified my *Question*. (Did I?)

Comment: @TarasBanakh: I cannot find the copy of $K_{3,3}$ you're referring to. Would you mind pointing it out more explicitly, perhaps by listing the coordinates?

Comment: @WillBrian Oh, sorry! I made a mistake thinking that there are two triangles (with vertices $(1,i)$ and $(2,i)$ for $i\in\{1,2,3\}$, but there are edges between these triabgkes, so they are not disjoint).

Answer (score 2):

Here are some bounds that I can extract from the dynamic survey [Small Ramsey Numbers](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS1) by Stanisław Radziszowski. Recall that for two graphs $G$ and $H$, $R(G,H)$ is the smallest integer $n$ such that every red-green edge colouring of $K_n$ contains a red $G$ subgraph or a green $H$ subgraph.  In this notation, $\mathrm{RK}_{rg}=R(K_5, K_{3,3})$.

**Claim.**
$13 \le \mathrm{RK}_{xx} \le 18.$

*Proof.* The lower bound $13 \le \mathrm{RK}_{xx}$ was proven by Will Brian in the  above comments.  For the upperbound, we have
$\mathrm{RK}_{xx} \le R(K_{3,3}, K_{3,3}) = 18$.  Note that $R(K_{3,3}, K_{3,3})=18$ was proven by H. Harborth and I. Mengersen in *The Ramsey Number of $K_{3,3}$* (see Section 3.3.1 of the survey). $\Box$

**Claim.** $21 \le \mathrm{RK}_{rg} \le 47$.

*Proof.* For the lowerbound, observe that $K_{5,5,5,5}$ does not contain $K_5$ and the complement of $K_{5,5,5,5}$ does not contain $K_{3,3}$.  For the upperbound, consider the edges incident to a fixed vertex. This gives the easy inductive bound $\mathrm{RK}_{rg} \le R(K_5, K_{2,3})+R(K_4, K_{3,3})+1$.  Repeating the argument, we obtain
$$\mathrm{RK}_{rg} \le R(K_5, K_{2,3}) + R(K_4, K_{2,3})+R(K_3, K_{3,3})+2.$$ In Section 5.9 of the survey, we have $R(B_3, K_4)=14$ and $R(B_3, K_5)=20$, where $B_3=K_2 + \overline{K_3}$.  Since $K_{2,3} \subseteq B_3$, we have $R(K_5, K_{2,3}) \le 20$, and $R(K_4, K_{2,3}) \le 14$.  Finally, in Section 3.2 of the survey, it is noted that $R(K_3, G)$ has been computed exactly for all connected graphs up to $9$ vertices.  The value of $R(K_3, K_{3,3})$ is not given explicitly in the survey, but tracking down the references, we have $R(K_3, K_{3,3})=11$.  Substituting, we obtain $\mathrm{RK}_{rg} \le 47$, as required. $\Box$

Finally, here is an upperbound for $\mathrm{RK}_{YY}$.

**Claim**. $\mathrm{RK}_{YY} \le 70$.

*Proof.* Since $K_6-e$ contains both $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$, we have $$\mathrm{RK}_{YY} \le R(K_6-e, K_6-e) \le 70$$ (see Section 3.1 of the survey). $\Box$